# OpenOffice Base locked

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-base

I ran into an issue with my open office base file.  It appears to be locked (I have file.odb and file.odb.lck).  Now I can open the base file, but as soon as I select **Tables** it crashes on me and when I open any of the **Reports**, it crashes on me.

How do I unlock it?  Or is it a different issue other than file lock?

Thanks!

**EDIT (13.VIII.2012, 12.54)** Let me add a bit more info.  It's openoffice 3.4, running on Windows XP pro 32-bit OS.  There is no screen shot I can get of you a crash, since as soon as I click on **Table** or trying to open any **Reports**, the file crashes and closes.  I can open the file, just can't do anything to it.

**EDIT  (13.VIII.2012, 13.00)**
Here is what the .lck file holds in it:

> HSQLLOCK  9 ¡&©

Let me know if that helps!

**EDIT (13.VIII.2012, 16.45)**

Here is the error message, I get after I try to save the file as...:

[image]

**EDIT (14.VIII.2012, 10.01)**

Hopefully, this one helps a little more:

[image]

Comment: I believe you can simply delete the lock file. Also, it might help to know the platform/version/&c that you're running on---in order to cite the relevant docs, if nothing else.

Comment: Please add more information about "crash" : Exact description of what you do, error messages text and if possible screenshots.

Comment: @harrymc Can't get you a screenshot as it's closes as soon as I click on either tables or try to open a report.

Comment: @nerdinexile No, that doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: You mean that OpenOffice itself crashes and disappears ? There may be some useful information about it in the Event Viewer (better look immediately after a crash). You could also verify if you have all permissions on the database files (renaming the .lck file is a good start).

Comment: One more question : What is your Java version and have you updated it just before the crash.

Comment: @harrymc There is no event in event viewer for any instances.  Actually, this particular version is Apache based.

Comment: The error dialog is hard to read - please post it by itself in real and readable size. But this is starting to look like your file is corrupted or is otherwise provoking a bug in Base.

Comment: @harrymc Hopefully this screenshot helps!

Comment: @George: Would you be willing to post the `.odb` file online?

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail I can't, it has some work related sensitive info, sorry.

Comment: 2 suggestions: (1) See if it also crashes Libreoffice. (2) An `.odb` file is just a renamed zip file; try unzipping and seeing whether you can access the HSQLDB data inside, outside of OO.

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess is all I can do : Your database is either corrupted or something in it causes Base (not known for stability) to crash.

Assuming that your database is dead, I suggest that you try at least to recover your data.
See this tutorial : [Recovering a damaged odb file](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=17125).

Let me know how this recovery procedure worked for you.

Comment: Well, I was able to follow the instructions, so thank you for providing them!  However, the **script** is fine, it's **data** appears to be corrupt.  I am screwed, ain't I?

Comment: [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=(Recover+OR+repair)+damaged+odb&btnG=Search&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=rcs) finds some repair products for odb files. However, they are all commercial although with trials available and some with money-back guarantee (for what's worth). I cannot recommend any of them since I never had this problem (never used OO). You could also try an [alternative free suite](http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/218394/microsoft_office_alternatives_productivity_software_showdown.html) and try to import your data.

Comment: ... for example [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) can probably open your database and might not suffer from the same bug. Google Docs may also be able to import your database.

Comment: I tried LibreOffice and it didn't work either.  I'll try google docs next, thanks!

Comment: In addition : IBM Lotus Symphony is based on OO, Zoho supports OO formats.